# Linker error with ATL on Mingw - undefined reference to `__imp__recalloc'

Tags: c++, mingw, atl

I am porting a project from Visual Studio to Mingw.I am getting the following linker error now

```
C:/mingw64/opt/atlmfc/include/atlsimpcoll.h:339: undefined reference to `__imp__recalloc'
```

I have included the `-latlsd` in my build options however I am sill getting this linker error. Any suggestions on how I might resolve it ?

Comment: I see it in x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcr100.a and friends, hard to avoid linking it.

Comment: That did the trick. Could you put that down as the answer